# Sort a table in ascending order by taking into account only a part of the value in a column

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

I want to sort a table in an ascending order, but the value of the field I need to sort by has a part that should not be considered for such sorting, since it is generated randomly and I do not want it to influence.

EXAMPLE: i have ES0420111112 and ES0120111113

In this case the value ES0420111112 is considered to be higher due to the initial 04, but I only want to take into account from the sixth value onwards when sorting, i.e. 111112

This way I would first show myself ES0420111112 and then ES0120111113

I have tried to create an auxiliary table like the previous one but cutting out the value of that column and sorting it later, but I don't know how to apply that filter order to the one I really want. Any idea how to do it? I suppose that the solution would have to do with the order of the "index" when comparing both tables.

Comment: What kind of table are you talking? Is this a DataTable or you are talking by a Table  getting by SQL. Where do you want  becomes the comparison (is that in SQL or in code)??

Comment: I thought it was clear because I put the tags vb.net and datatable, but I mean in code with vb.net  "Dim dt as Datatable"

Answer (score 0):

Do you had in mind something like this?

```
 Try

        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable
        table.Columns.Add("Column1")

        For i As Integer = 111 To 0 Step -2
            Dim row As DataRow = table.NewRow
            row.Item("Column1") = "ES012011111" & i.ToString
            table.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        Dim orderedRows = From record In table
                          Select Column1 = record.Item("Column1"),
                                 ColumnForOrder = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(CStr(record.Item("Column1")), 6)
                          Order By ColumnForOrder Ascending


        For Each row In orderedRows
            Console.WriteLine("Column1: " & row.Column1.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("ColumnForOrder: " & row.ColumnForOrder)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```